# Immutable Value Of Type [AnyObject] Only Has Mutating Members named 'removeAtIndex'

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a core data subclass called `Folder`. It has an attribute called items which is a `NSOrderedSet` of a `Item` class. I have a function that returns a sorted array of Items for a folder instance to display in a `UITableView` but I cannot `removeAtIndex` because of the following error;

> Immutable Value Of Type [AnyObject] Only Has Mutating Members named
>   'removeAtIndex'

That is for the following code when removing items from the table view.

```
 context.deleteObject(selectedFolder.itemArray()[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject )
 selectedFolder.itemArray().removeAtIndex(indexPath.row) //error occurs here
```

Here is my code for the subclass where I create my function:

```
class Folder: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var title: String
@NSManaged var details: String
@NSManaged var date: NSDate
@NSManaged var item: NSOrderedSet


func itemsArray() -> [Item] {
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
    return item.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sortDescriptor]) as! [Item]
}

}
```

How can I make my array of anyobject mutable to remove items of the instance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type is constant array which is immutable. You should create a copy of the array to make it mutable. And value type are copied in Swift when you simply assign it to another variable.

```
var itemArray = selectedFolder.itemArray() // notice var which makes it mutable
itemArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
```

And, use itemArray then after.